# Handle external interrupts while switching activities in an App

Tags: android

I Have developed an application which contains many activity.

I have noticed an issue while one activity starts another activity and meanwhile if we press camera button or get a call my application hangs and never recovers even after ending the call or closing the camera.

Basically what I want to know is how to handle external interrupts(alarms, calls, camera) so that my app resumes from where it had stopped.

I am replicating this issues on emulator as well as on LG Device.Can anyone give me some idea to how to handle onpause and onrsume function call in this case.

Thanks

Comment: Where does it hang? Seems like you're not handling the activity clean-up correctly.

Comment: Hi thanks for response. Actually when i am launching the application a splash activity starts followed by main-activity, And if i am pressing camera button before loading main-activity my application getting stuck at splash activity itself even after closing the camera.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do clean-up.? Thanks in advance